# SAS - Proc Report - Issue with multiple worksheets in an XLS file

Tags: sas, proc-report

I'm having some problems with proc report and I'm not sure if that's where the problem lies or if it's possibly a SAS option somewhere. As an example, The code below should create an XLS file named filename.xls with two sheets in it. One called Summary, and the other called Detail. Instead, it is creating two XLS files, filename.xls which contains the Summary sheet, and filename1.xls which contains the Detail sheet.

I've used code similar to this many times before and haven't run into this issue. I've tried closing and reopening SAS, as well as rebooting my PC with no luck. Also, I've tried running other programs, that I know work, which contain similar proc reports, and now they all have this issue as well. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
ods listing close;
ods results off;
ods tagsets.excelxp file="c:\temp\filename.xls" style=ESGExcel 
    options(sheet_name='summary'
            embedded_titles='yes' 
            embedded_footnotes='yes'
            frozen_headers='1'
            );

proc report data = ds1 missing nowindows;
    columns   OWN
              ABR
              BBR
                ;

    label       OWN = 'SOMETHING1'
                ABR = 'SOMETHING2'
                BBR = 'SOMETHING3'
                ;

    define OWN / 
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in};
    define ABR / 
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define BBR /  
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    title; 
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp style=ESGExcel 
    options(sheet_name='detail'
            embedded_titles='yes' 
            embedded_footnotes='yes'
            frozen_headers='1'
            );

proc report data = ds2 missing nowindows;
    columns   BSN
              LSQ
              OWN
                ;

    label       BSN = 'SOMETHING1'
                LSQ = 'SOMETHING2'
                OWN = 'SOMETHING3'
                ;

    define BSN / 
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in};
    define LSQ / 
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    define OWN /  
                style(header)={font=('calibri',10pt,bold) just=c}
                style(column)={font=('calibri',10pt) just=c cellwidth=1.0in}; 
    title; 
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
ods listing;
ods results;
```

Comment: This works fine for me as you say.  Can you try rerunning the EXcel tagset code ([found here](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excltags.tpl) )?  Perhaps yours got corrupted.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. It was a good thought though.

Comment: I would look to something with your installation, then.  This is desktop SAS?  Any chance something was changed in your config files or something else?

Comment: Yep, it's desktop SAS. I actualyl just stumbled onto the solution. Tools>Options>Preferences...under the results tab, turned off "Create HTML" and now everything works fine. Weird.

Comment: Write that as an answer then.  Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: In desktop SAS, go to Tools > Options > Preferences. Under the Results tab, uncheck "Create HTML".